# Is it possible to make 2 different PUT requests or GET requests on one route for Expressjs?

Tags: express, get, routes, put, meanjs

For example, say this is a quiz app with admin (professor) roles, and user (student) roles. The professor is allowed to make a course (which is a CRUD module) and only he is allowed to update it (hasAuthorization). When the student joins the course, the course roster needs to update has well, but the student does not have sufficient privileges, therefore, I made another function designed specifically to update roles. Cut to the chase, here's the code:

```js
 app.route('/courses/:courseId')
  .get(courses.read)
  .put(users.requiresLogin, courses.hasAuthorization, courses.update)
  .put(users.requiresLogin, courses.updateRoster)
  .delete(users.requiresLogin, courses.hasAuthorization, courses.delete);
```

Right now, it only takes in the first PUT when I perform anything that uses the PUT request (ie. update() course, or joinCourse()). Is there a way I can use both PUT requests one after another?

Comment: I thinks you just need one put, and you can add your `updateRoster` function to it  `.put(users.requiresLogin, courses.hasAuthorization, courses.update, courses.updateRoster)`

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I don't want to have courses.hasAuthorization for updateRoster. However, I do want it with courses.update.

Comment: I did a complete workaround to solve my particular problem by taking out hasAuthorization and updateRoster all together. I had courses.update do both course updating for the owner, and roster updating when someone joins the course. Simplified, and would only need 1 PUT.